# UISplitViewController with UINavigationController as Details View: push controller via Storyboard segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

My current Storyboard is set like this:

[image: Storyboard layout]

(Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nk6K.png)

There is a Split View Controller, with two Navigation Controller. The Master's Navigation Controller has a Table View with different cells (yellow); the Details' Navigation Controller has a Collection View (green) with different cells (blue). By tapping the blue and the yellow cells, a corresponding View Controller (red) is opened in the Details' Navigation Controller.

As you can see, there is a segue connecting the **yellow cell** to the **red view**. The segue is of the kind `Show Detail (e.g. Replace)`. What I would like it to do is to show the red view in the Details View within the existing Navigation Controller. However, what happens is that the whole Detail's Navigation Controller is replaced and the Detail View of the Split View only shows the red View Controller, without any navigation bar.

Can this be done only using the Storyboard or with some specific code?

The only way I found to do this is to implement this in the Master's View Controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    PostViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PostView"]; // instantiate the red view controller
    [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Which works; it's not a lot of code, but it feels like a trick?

Comment: Is it important that it is pushed onto the same navigation stack, or just that it has a navigation bar, title etc?

Comment: Actually there's no actual need for that. Would you suggest adding a navigation bar to the red view? Because that would require two different (red) views in the Storyboard, so I would need to duplicate its whole layout…

Answer (score 1):

Could you embed the red view in a navigation controller and link the replace detail from the master VC to the new navigation controller?

You haven't said what the segue is connecting the green vc to the red VC, but this could either stay connected directly to the red VC and be changed to a push, or connected to the new navigation controller.

Comment: This might work but I would lose the connection with the green navigation controller, so I wouldn't have a “back” button to return to it. The green vc is connected to the red is connected with a normal push. I'll consider this idea though if I don't find any other solution, as I haven't decided yet some details about the logic of going back and forth.

Comment: It sounds like an odd navigation structure If you can go yellow-red-green. Where did green come from?